# Why RecyclerView always create its items while scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using `RecyclerView` and something bad makes me think about why `RecyclerView` always create its items while scrolling?

My `RecyclerView` items will be recreated if I scroll vertically and it happens always but that's not right because an item has been created already and not to be recreated while the adapter has not changed, right?

**Note:** I'm using Volley and Picasso. Both of them will fetch images for the first time and when I scroll the list they will remove them and put them back immediately.

**My `RecyclerView`:**

```
public class PersonTimelineAdapter extends UltimateViewAdapter<PersonTimelineAdapter.CellFeedViewHolder>
        implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final DecelerateInterpolator DECCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR = new DecelerateInterpolator();
    private static final AccelerateInterpolator ACCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR = new AccelerateInterpolator();
    private static final OvershootInterpolator OVERSHOOT_INTERPOLATOR = new OvershootInterpolator(4);

    private final Context context;
    private final List<CompactPost> mPosts;

    private OnFeedItemClickListener onFeedItemClickListener;

    private final Map<RecyclerView.ViewHolder, AnimatorSet> likeAnimations = new HashMap<>();
    private final ArrayList<Integer> likedPositions = new ArrayList<>();
    private final String mCurrentProfileId = Logged.Models.getUserProfile().getId().toString();

    public PersonTimelineAdapter(Context context, List<CompactPost> postList) {
        this.context = context;
        mPosts = postList;
    }

    @Override
    public CellFeedViewHolder getViewHolder(View view) {
        return new CellFeedViewHolder(view, false);
    }

    @Override
    public CellFeedViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_person_profile_timeline, viewGroup,
                        false);
        CellFeedViewHolder cellFeedViewHolder = new CellFeedViewHolder(view, true);

        cellFeedViewHolder.btnComments.setOnClickListener(this);
        cellFeedViewHolder.btnMore.setOnClickListener(this);
        cellFeedViewHolder.postPicture.setOnClickListener(this);
        cellFeedViewHolder.likeImageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        cellFeedViewHolder.profilePicture.setOnClickListener(this);
        cellFeedViewHolder.likesContainer.setOnClickListener(this);

        return cellFeedViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CellFeedViewHolder viewHolder, int
            position) {
        bindFeedItem(position, viewHolder);
    }

    private void setPostPicture(CompactPost post, CellFeedViewHolder holder) {
        String imagePath = Constants.General.PROTOCOL + post.getImageAddress();

        ImageLoader imageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        holder.postPicture.setImageUrl(imagePath, imageLoader);
    }

    private void setProfilePicture(CompactPost post, final CellFeedViewHolder holder) {
        String imagePath = Constants.General.PROTOCOL + post.getSender().getImageAddress();

        Cache cache = MyApplication.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
        Cache.Entry entry = cache.get(imagePath);
        if (entry != null) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(entry.data, 0, entry.data.length);
            holder.profilePicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } else {
            ImageLoader imageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance().getImageLoader();

            imageLoader.get(imagePath, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean arg1) {
                    if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                        holder.profilePicture.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void bindFeedItem(int position, final CellFeedViewHolder holder) {
        CompactPost item = mPosts.get(position);
        holder.nameTextView.setText(item.getSender().getName());

        int likesCount = item.getLikes().size();
        holder.likesTextView.setText(Integer.toString(likesCount));

        if (item.getSender().getImageAddress() != null) {
            setProfilePicture(item, holder);
        }
        holder.profilePicture.setTag(item.getSender());

        holder.postDateTime.setText(Utils.getTimeAgo(Utils.stringToDate(context, item
                .getInsertTime())
                .getTime()));

        if (item.getImageAddress() != null) {
            holder.videoCC.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            setPostPicture(item, holder);
            holder.imageCC.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.postPictureContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (item.getVideoAddress() != null) {
            //IMPLEMENT add video
            holder.imageCC.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            String videoPath = Constants.General.PROTOCOL + item.getVideoAddress();
            //holder.videoView.setScaleType(TextureVideoView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            holder.videoView.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse(videoPath));
            holder.videoView.play();

            holder.videoCC.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.postPictureContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        // No video and no Image
        else {
            holder.postPictureContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        holder.btnComments.setTag(item);

        if (!item.getText().isEmpty()) {
            holder.postTextTextView.setText(item.getText());
            holder.postTextTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        holder.likesTextView.setText(Integer.toString(item.getLikes().size()));

        holder.footerContainer.setTag(item);

        holder.btnMore.setTag(item.getId() + "," + position);

        Hashtable<CellFeedViewHolder, CompactPost> hashtagPost = new Hashtable<>();
        hashtagPost.put(holder, item);
        holder.postPicture.setTag(hashtagPost);

        Hashtable<CellFeedViewHolder, String> hashtableTag = new Hashtable<>();
        hashtableTag.put(holder, "false");
        holder.likeImageButton.setTag(hashtableTag);

        if (item.getLikes().contains(mCurrentProfileId)) {
            hashtableTag.put(holder, "true");
            holder.likeImageButton.setTag(hashtableTag);
            holder.likeImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart);
        } else {
            holder.likeImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart_outline);
        }

        holder.likesContainer.setTag(item.getId());

        if (likeAnimations.containsKey(holder)) {
            likeAnimations.get(holder).cancel();
        }
        resetLikeAnimationState(holder);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateHeaderViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        super.getItemCount();
        return mPosts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getAdapterItemCount() {
        return mPosts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long generateHeaderId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    private void updateHeartButton(final CellFeedViewHolder holder, boolean animated) {
        if (animated) {
            if (!likeAnimations.containsKey(holder)) {
                AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
                likeAnimations.put(holder, animatorSet);

                ObjectAnimator rotationAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.likeImageButton, "rotation", 0f, 360f);
                rotationAnim.setDuration(300);
                rotationAnim.setInterpolator(ACCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR);

                ObjectAnimator bounceAnimX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.likeImageButton, "scaleX", 0.2f, 1f);
                bounceAnimX.setDuration(300);
                bounceAnimX.setInterpolator(OVERSHOOT_INTERPOLATOR);

                ObjectAnimator bounceAnimY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.likeImageButton, "scaleY", 0.2f, 1f);
                bounceAnimY.setDuration(300);
                bounceAnimY.setInterpolator(OVERSHOOT_INTERPOLATOR);
                bounceAnimY.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                        holder.likeImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart);
                    }
                });

                animatorSet.play(rotationAnim);
                animatorSet.play(bounceAnimX).with(bounceAnimY).after(rotationAnim);

                animatorSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        resetLikeAnimationState(holder);
                    }
                });

                animatorSet.start();
            }
        } else {
            if (likedPositions.contains(holder.getPosition())) {
                holder.likeImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart);
            } else {
                holder.likeImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart_outline);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setOnFeedItemClickListener(OnFeedItemClickListener onFeedItemClickListener) {
        this.onFeedItemClickListener = onFeedItemClickListener;
    }

    private void likePost(final CellFeedViewHolder holder, final CompactPost post) {

        updateLikesCount(holder);

        HttpClient.get(String.format(Constants.Server.GET_POST_LIKE, post.getId(),
                mCurrentProfileId), new
                AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                        CompactPost newPost = GsonParser.getObjectFromGson(responseBody, CompactPost.class);
                        updatePostsObject(post, newPost);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.toast_error_like),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                        updateUnlikes(holder);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void updateLikesCount(final CellFeedViewHolder holder) {
        int likesCount = Integer.parseInt(holder.likesTextView
                .getText().toString()) + 1;
        holder.likesTextView.setText(Integer.toString(likesCount));
        updateHeartButton(holder, true);
        Hashtable<CellFeedViewHolder, String> hashTags = new Hashtable<>();
        hashTags.put(holder, "true");
        holder.likeImageButton.setTag(hashTags);
        holder.likeImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart);
    }

    private void updateUnlikes(final CellFeedViewHolder holder) {
        int likesCount = Integer.parseInt(holder.likesTextView
                .getText().toString()) - 1;
        holder.likesTextView.setText(Integer.toString(likesCount));
        holder.likeImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart_outline);
        Hashtable<CellFeedViewHolder, String> hashTags = new Hashtable<>();
        hashTags.put(holder, "false");
        holder.likeImageButton.setTag(hashTags);
    }

    private void updatePostsObject(CompactPost oldPost, CompactPost newPost) {
        int postId = mPosts.indexOf(oldPost);
        mPosts.add(postId, newPost);
    }

    private void unlikePost(final CellFeedViewHolder holder, final CompactPost post) {

        updateUnlikes(holder);

        HttpClient.get(String.format(Constants.Server.GET_POST_UNLIKE, post.getId()
                , mCurrentProfileId), new
                AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                        CompactPost newPost = GsonParser.getObjectFromGson(responseBody, CompactPost.class);
                        updatePostsObject(post, newPost);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.toast_error_like),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                        updateLikesCount(holder);
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.image_button_comments:
                CompactPost post = (CompactPost) view.getTag();
                if (onFeedItemClickListener != null) {
                    onFeedItemClickListener.onCommentsClick(view, post);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.image_button_more:
                String tag = (String) view.getTag();
                String[] splittedTags = tag.split(",");
                String postId = splittedTags[0];
                int position = Integer.parseInt(splittedTags[1]);
                if (onFeedItemClickListener != null) {
                    onFeedItemClickListener.onMoreClick(view, postId, position);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.image_button_like_small:
                CompactPost post2 = (CompactPost) ((LinearLayout) view.getParent()).getTag();
                final Hashtable hashTags = (Hashtable<CellFeedViewHolder, String>) view
                        .getTag();
                CellFeedViewHolder holder = (CellFeedViewHolder) hashTags.keys().nextElement();
                String isLiked = (String) hashTags.values().iterator().next();
                if (isLiked.equals("false")) {
                    likePost(holder, post2);
                } else {
                    unlikePost(holder, post2);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.image_view_post_picture:
                final Hashtable postPictureTags = (Hashtable<CellFeedViewHolder, Post>) view
                        .getTag();
                CellFeedViewHolder postPictureHolder = (CellFeedViewHolder) postPictureTags.keys()
                        .nextElement();
                CompactPost postPicturePost = (CompactPost) postPictureTags.values()
                        .iterator()
                        .next();
                Hashtable<CellFeedViewHolder, String> btnLikeTags = (Hashtable<CellFeedViewHolder, String>) postPictureHolder
                        .likeImageButton.getTag();

                if (btnLikeTags.values().iterator().next().equals("false")) {
                    animatePhotoLike(postPictureHolder);
                    likePost(postPictureHolder, postPicturePost);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.linear_layout_post_likes:
                postId = (String) view.getTag();
                if (onFeedItemClickListener != null) {
                    onFeedItemClickListener.onLikesCountClick(postId);
                }
                break;

            case R.id.image_view_picture:
                if (onFeedItemClickListener != null) {
                    CompactProfile profile = (CompactProfile) view.getTag();
                    onFeedItemClickListener.onProfileClick(profile);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void animatePhotoLike(final CellFeedViewHolder holder) {
        holder.vBgLike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.ivLike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        holder.vBgLike.setScaleY(0.1f);
        holder.vBgLike.setScaleX(0.1f);
        holder.vBgLike.setAlpha(1f);
        holder.ivLike.setScaleY(0.1f);
        holder.ivLike.setScaleX(0.1f);

        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();

        ObjectAnimator bgScaleYAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.vBgLike, "scaleY", 0.1f, 1f);
        bgScaleYAnim.setDuration(200);
        bgScaleYAnim.setInterpolator(DECCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR);
        ObjectAnimator bgScaleXAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.vBgLike, "scaleX", 0.1f, 1f);
        bgScaleXAnim.setDuration(200);
        bgScaleXAnim.setInterpolator(DECCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR);
        ObjectAnimator bgAlphaAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.vBgLike, "alpha", 1f, 0f);
        bgAlphaAnim.setDuration(200);
        bgAlphaAnim.setStartDelay(150);
        bgAlphaAnim.setInterpolator(DECCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR);

        ObjectAnimator imgScaleUpYAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.ivLike, "scaleY", 0.1f, 1f);
        imgScaleUpYAnim.setDuration(300);
        imgScaleUpYAnim.setInterpolator(DECCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR);
        ObjectAnimator imgScaleUpXAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.ivLike, "scaleX", 0.1f, 1f);
        imgScaleUpXAnim.setDuration(300);
        imgScaleUpXAnim.setInterpolator(DECCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR);

        ObjectAnimator imgScaleDownYAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.ivLike, "scaleY", 1f, 0f);
        imgScaleDownYAnim.setDuration(300);
        imgScaleDownYAnim.setInterpolator(ACCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR);
        ObjectAnimator imgScaleDownXAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.ivLike, "scaleX", 1f, 0f);
        imgScaleDownXAnim.setDuration(300);
        imgScaleDownXAnim.setInterpolator(ACCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR);

        animatorSet.playTogether(bgScaleYAnim, bgScaleXAnim, bgAlphaAnim, imgScaleUpYAnim, imgScaleUpXAnim);
        animatorSet.play(imgScaleDownYAnim).with(imgScaleDownXAnim).after(imgScaleUpYAnim);

        animatorSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                resetLikeAnimationState(holder);
            }
        });
        animatorSet.start();
    }

    private void resetLikeAnimationState(CellFeedViewHolder holder) {
        likeAnimations.remove(holder);
        holder.vBgLike.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.ivLike.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public interface OnFeedItemClickListener {
        void onCommentsClick(View v, CompactPost post);

        void onMoreClick(View view, String postId, int position);

        void onProfileClick(CompactProfile profile);

        void onLikesCountClick(String postId);
    }

    public static class CellFeedViewHolder extends UltimateRecyclerviewViewHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.image_view_post_picture)
        NetworkImageView postPicture;
        @Bind(R.id.image_button_comments)
        ImageButton btnComments;
        @Bind(R.id.image_button_like_small)
        ImageButton likeImageButton;
        @Bind(R.id.image_button_more)
        ImageButton btnMore;
        @Bind(R.id.vBgLike)
        View vBgLike;
        @Bind(R.id.ivLike)
        ImageView ivLike;
        @Bind(R.id.text_view_name)
        TextView nameTextView;
        @Bind(R.id.image_view_picture)
        CircleImageView profilePicture;
        @Bind(R.id.text_view_likes)
        TextView likesTextView;
        @Bind(R.id.linear_layout_footer_container)
        LinearLayout footerContainer;
        @Bind(R.id.squared_frame_layout_post_image_container)
        SquaredFrameLayout postPictureContainer;
        @Bind(R.id.text_view_text)
        TextView postTextTextView;
        @Bind(R.id.linear_layout_post_likes)
        LinearLayout likesContainer;
        @Bind(R.id.text_view_datetime)
        TextView postDateTime;
        @Bind(R.id.image_cc)
        FrameLayout imageCC;
        @Bind(R.id.video_cc)
        FrameLayout videoCC;
        @Bind(R.id.cropTextureView)
        TextureVideoView videoView;

        public CellFeedViewHolder(View view, boolean isItem) {
            super(view);
            if (isItem) {
                ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
                postPicture.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.ic_file_image_box_2);
                postPicture.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.ic_file_image_box_2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you're items are always being creating ? How are you figuring that out,  they should be re-binded only

Comment: @forcewill I put a break point on the `onBindViewHolder` method and that always will be called even previous items which are created already. I'm using Volley and Picasso and both of them will fetch the image for the first time and when I scroll the list they will remove the image and put it back immediately.

Comment: thats the expect behaviour the ´RecyclerView' will reuse the Views, but will need to bind the actual data to those reuse views as you scroll, otherwise it would have to hold all views & data in memory

Comment: @Alireza maybe picasso is caching the images, so will donwload less information from web. Almost you can take a look to Glide (similar to picasso) that has good features to. Here's a link for a comparission beetween Picasso-Glide. : http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

Answer (score 1):

Copied from my comment since it was pretty long

If you check for instance the google market app that happens if you scroll down and then scroll up fast you can see the images being faded in from empty image views.

In a memory constrained device you just can't just have all those views and images sitting around in memory, thats why Picasso, Volley and other have memory and disk caches with configurable sizes.
If the images takes too long to "reappear", remember to cancel the request for each request no longer necessary as you're reusing a view if you scroll down pass a view and you're start the loading of an image with url X, then continue scrolling down and that view gets "thrown" out and then reused again for another data item then you should cancel X load request to load the new one, that could be having some impact on the time it takes to the images reappear since unused images will still be loading before the new one 
actually since you're using `NetworkImageView` that ain't necessary since it [does](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r1/com/android/volley/toolbox/NetworkImageView.java#NetworkImageView.loadImageIfNecessary%28boolean%29) that automatically for you.

Just to point out that the lines

```
 Cache cache = MyApplication.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
    Cache.Entry entry = cache.get(imagePath);
    if (entry != null) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(entry.data, 0, entry.data.length);
        holder.profilePicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

seem to me unnecessary since volley will attempt to load from [cache](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r1/com/android/volley/toolbox/ImageLoader.java#ImageLoader.get%28java.lang.String%2Ccom.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageListener%29) first and only them will do the remote request

You could also pre request images that will be necessary before hand, for example if your scrolling down and at the index X, you could ask volley to load images X+1, X+2, X+n so when they come into view, they will be already in cache

Comment: Thank you and thanks for your time. As you said, If I use `NetworkImageView` then it does caching automatically and there is no need to do it manually. I'm already using the `NetworkImageView`! I must note that I load images from local and loading images will not take long and only scrolling quickly shows what's wrong.